# Prisma following/follower relationship schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, database-design, prisma

I have a user model, and i want to add following/followers system, and for that i think i need to create a separate table that looks like this

```
id | user_id | follower_id
1  | 20      | 45
2  | 20      | 53
3  | 32      | 20
```

but i have no idea how to create the schema for that, what I've done is this:

```
model User {
  id         Int         @id @default(autoincrement())
  username   String
  Follows    Follows[]
}

model Follows {
  id           Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  following_id Int?
  follower_id  Int?
  user_Following    User     @relation(fields: [following_id], references: [id])
  user_Follower     User     @relation(fields: [follower_id], references: [id])
}
```

but that of course doesn't work and is giving me an error

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's the way I'd suggest modeling your schema.

```
model User {
  id        String  @id @default(autoincrement())
  username  String
  followers Follows[] @relation("following")
  following Follows[] @relation("follower")
}

model Follows {
  follower    User @relation("follower", fields: [followerId], references: [id])
  followerId  String
  following   User @relation("following", fields: [followingId], references: [id])
  followingId String

  @@id([followerId, followingId])
}
```

Changes

1. User table has two relation fields instead of one.
2. `followerId` and `followingId` are made mandatory. It doesn't really make sense to have a `Follows` relation table when either of those are absent. (You can't have a following relationship without one user following and one user to follow).
3. `@@id([followerId, followingId])` represents the primary key in `Follows` table. A separate `id` field is redundant.
4. Changed field names to camelCase, which is the recommended convention in Prisma.

4 is optional ofcourse, but I'd suggest following it none the less.

You can find more details about this in the many-to-many subsection of the [self-reation article](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/self-relations) in the Prisma doc.

Comment: I think you made a small mistake, the relation annotation should be switched in the User Model.  followers = "following" and following = "follower".
Look here https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/self-relations#many-to-many-self-relations

Comment: That would make more sense. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

In Mongodb use this for self-realtion:

```json
model User {
  id            String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name          String?
  followedBy    User[]   @relation("UserFollows", fields: [followedByIDs], references: [id])
  followedByIDs String[] @db.ObjectId
  following     User[]   @relation("UserFollows", fields: [followingIDs], references: [id])
  followingIDs  String[] @db.ObjectId
}
```